# Color Menu Chooser

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

How can I make a color chooser for text to use in my cocoa app?  I am trying to get the same color selection menu like used on microsoft word.  Would this be a popup button or color well or what?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally recommend that you don't emulate Microsoft's UI. It looks very un-Mac-like and you can do better.

You could implement something like this as a popup button and in the button's menu, use custom views for the various color picker sections. Apple's [MenuItemView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/MenuItemView/Introduction/Intro.html) example code shows how to use custom views in menu items.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a standard Cocoa control, so you'll have to come up with your own implementation if you want your picker to look just like that. You'd probably be better off using the standard Cocoa controls for colors, though -- they're used in many programs, so users will already be familiar with them. There's NSColorWell, which displays a single color, and NSColorPicker, which provides a user interface for selecting a color. Read about both in [*Color Programming Topics*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DrawColor/DrawColor.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000082-SW1).